# How to import a csv file with null to SQL Workbench

Tags: sql, csv, mysql-workbench, importerror

I am having issues importing the dataset to SQL bc it has null values which are part of the data. It either erases the null and shortens my count which is not what I want. I want to be able to import it with the null values. I am using the schemas to create a table -> name of the table "the" -> using wizard import. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: It "shortens my count"? The question is a bit unclear. Do you mean the csv file literally contains `NULL` values, like `123,Johnson,NULL,01-01-1980` or something like that? And the import skips the entire line, so those lines are not imported at all?

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out, I can use the import wizard to import new data. Instead of using existing data (which is creating a new table and adding its characteristics), I made a new table and imported the null values.